# Will nicotine gum (e.g., Nicorette) harm my singing voice?

Tags: voice, health, vocal-cords

Since about the age of 30 (I'm 35 now) I have sometimes been addicted to smoking tobacco.  I know that smoking tobacco can damage my singing voice--I have experienced this personally.  Lately, I had quit again, but then I moved in with a roommate who smokes a lotta cigarettes, as do his friends--who have become my friends--and I have started smoking cigarettes and/or Black n Milds (cigarillos) again.  I just very recently started chewing nicotine gum (generic version of Nicorette) to lead me to smoking little to none again.

I have searched on Google, and I can't find anyone talking about whether nicotine gum does or does not harm the singing voice.  Anyone have any knowledge on this?

Note: I don't plan on cutting nicotine out of my life entirely, in the immediate future; rather, I want to use nicotine gum to satisfy my cravings, while still enjoying a cigarette or Black n Mild occasionally with my friends who smoke.  This means that I may be chewing nicotine gum for quite some time.

Comment: As a singer, you're an athlete. You will have to keep "in training" all the time. There are no off- seasons for singers (hopefully).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Nicotine supplements will damage your voice. As will smoking and being around people who are smoking.

According to *The Singer's Voice*, by Michael S. Benninger and Thomas Murry (Plural Publishing, 2008) (LINK: [Book at Publisher's Website](https://www.pluralpublishing.com/publications/the-singers-voice)), nicotine supplements should be avoided (p. 94, Table 9.1) and they can cause vocal dryness (p. 95, Table 9.2).

The below images are screenshots from [Google Books](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Singer_s_Voice/oHgiCAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=singing%20voice%20nicotine%20gum&pg=PA95&printsec=frontcover)

**Excerpt from *The Singer's Voice*, p. 94, Table 9.1**
[image: Table headings: "Common Complaint", "Recommended Drug Therapy"]
[image: Nicotine supplement entry]

**Excerpt from *The Singer's Voice*, p. 95, Table 9.2**
[image: Table headings: "Drug Type", "Examples That Induce Dryness", "Safe Alternatives"]
[image: Nicotine supplement entry]

In addition, the [Mayo Clinic](https://www.mayoclinic.org/drugs-supplements/nicotine-oral-route-oromucosal-route/side-effects/drg-20122519?p=1) lists the following possible side effects (among others) for Nicorette:

- Mouth sores, blisters, or irritation
- sore throat
- belching
- hiccups
- mouth, tooth, jaw, or neck pain

all of which could affect singing.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Nicorette gum has a damaging effect on the vocal cords. I am a singer, and it has coated my vocal cords, and has affected my singing.

Answer (score 2):

I was using Nicorette gum for a few years and finally had to quit when I realized it was the cause of my voice going hoarse. It damaged vocal chords and it took me over a month to get my voice back with the help of ginger, lemon and honey tea. Stay away from Nicorette gum.